# Sorting by 'last' in Jekyll doesn't work? Reverse-sorting, etc

Tags: sorting, jekyll, liquid

I'm on version 3.8.4. Say I have made an array that I want to print in reverse order:

```
{% assign words = 'swag, yolo, hi' | split: ", " | sort: 'last' %}

{% for word in words %}

    <p>{{word}}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Even with `sort: 'last'`, this will print as:

```
swag
yolo
hi
```

Maybe it's `'first'`. The output is still

```
swag
yolo
hi
```

with `'first'`.

I've been trying to sort a collection in Jekyll by some page front-matter, and `sort` works--it lists everything in order, by the numbers I gave them (not by title or date), first to last, but what if I want it last to first? If I `sort: 'last'`, it's still sorted first to last. Is the `last` option broken? Am I doing something wrong?

Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/omYYQ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks from [the docs](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/sort/) like `sort` always goes one way. The argument you pass to it is the name of the property to sort on. Your objects don't have properties named 'first' or 'last', so it's being ignored.

To get what you want, just use `sort` to sort a-z, and then `reverse` to reverse the sorted list (z-a):

`{% assign words = 'swag, yolo, hi' | split: ", " | sort | reverse %}`

Comment: First and last is just an option on how to treat Nil values. If it's `first`, then they would appear first in the result - before non-empty values. If it's `last`, then Nils are pushed  to the end of the result

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: It's always best to refer to the only source of truth - the source code: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/filters.rb#L229